# Library Branch Circulation Problem - Terminology and References

Tags: terminology, optimization

This is a bit general, but is there a name to this type of problem? It looks like a directed graph traversal problem, but you have multiple paths going on, and timing may be important.

> You operate a public library system with multiple branches. Every day,
>   people check out and return materials. Library users can return
>   materials at any branch. Additionally, library users can place a hold
>   on an item and ask to pick it up at any branch. Essentially, on any
>   given day you have items that need to be delivered between library
>   branches.
>
> You have hired a set number of drivers to move materials between
>   locations. Assume that the transit time between branches is known and
>   time-invariant, the carrying capacity of the vehicles is unlimited,
>   drivers are on for a set amount of time each day, and the drivers can
>   start and end at any library branch. Given a list of what must be
>   moved, is there an optimal set of delivery routes that minimizes
>   driving time?

Comment: Okay, so to clarify the problem:

Given an edge-weighted graph $G = (V, E), w : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, a set of ordered pairs of vertices $\{(v_1, w_1), (v_2, w_2), \ldots (v_n, w_n) \}$, and a positive integer $m$, we want to find $m$ paths through $G$ such that:

(1) For each pair $(v_i, w_i)$, one of the paths visits $v_i$ before $w_i$.

(2) The maximum of the $m$ path lengths is minimal with respect to property (1).

Correct?

Comment: My graph theory is not very strong, but the description that you give appears to be accurate. Property (1) being that the maximum of the $m$ (weighted) path lengths is bounded above by a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things simple, I'll assume that any book that goes onto a truck must be delivered to its destination by that truck (and not, say, switched from one truck to another).
 Let ${\cal M}$ be the set of ordered pairs of branches $(a,b)$ such that at least one book has to go from branch $a$ to branch $b$.
Since the carrying capacity is unlimited, you just have to make sure that if $(a,b) \in {\cal M}$, there is a truck that is at $b$ at some time after it is at $a$. 
Let $\cal R$ be the set of all possible routes for trucks (i.e. lists of branches that could be visited in the given order within the time allotted).  We may assume a branch can occur at most twice in a route.  Let $c(R)$ be the total driving time for route $R$, and $P(R)$ the set of $(a,b) \in \cal M$  such that the first $a$ occurs before the last $b$ in route $R$ (so this route could deliver books from $a$ to $b$).  Then what you have is an optimal set-covering problem: find a subset $\cal S$ of $\cal R$ with cardinality at most $d$ (the number of drivers) that minimizes $\sum_{R \in {\cal S}} c(R)$ subject to the constraint that $\bigcup_{R \in {\cal S}} P(R) = \cal M$.